# Why is my object appearing as a struct in the debugger?

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging

Set breakpoints, run code. The code pauses and your variables view pops up.

Usually everything is exactly as I'd expect. My objects have little triangles and I can open them up and poke about their contents. Sometimes though they are listed as structs. It looks something like...

```
myCar = (struct Car *) 0x8d85430
```

and it provides no handle triangle to expand and examine the object. I go to the Console view and type in things like `po myCar.color` to check out the details so it's more of an annoyance than anything else. I notice my objects appear as structs in consistent locations in my code and look like objects in other locations fairly consistently, I'm just stumped as to the reason.

I would love to have some light shed on the reasons for this phenomenon.

Edit: Added some code. This is a real code example where it occurs... sometimes. The code below are snippets from a sub-class of NSObject implementing `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols.

Sometimes my `formatCell` appears as a struct when I hit a breakpoint in `transactionDisclaimerCellHeight:` Right clicking and doing a "Print Description" on the variable print the normal description you'd expect from a `UITableViewCell`

```
-(id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        formatCell = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TransactionCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject] retain];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSNumber *)transactionDisclaimerCellHeight:(UITableView *)tableView {
    CGRect cellFrame = formatCell.frame;
    cellFrame.size.width = [self guesstimateCellWidthFromTableWidth:tableView.frame.size.width];
    formatCell.frame = cellFrame;

    formatCell.subLabel.text = dataStore.disclaimer;
    [RetailUtil dynamicallySizeLabelHeightFor:formatCell.subLabel];
    CGFloat cellHeight = [[self getDefaultCellHeight:tableView] floatValue] + formatCell.subLabel.frame.size.height;

    return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:cellHeight];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGFloat rowHeight = tableView.rowHeight;

    if (indexPath.section == kTransactionDetailsSection) {
        NSNumber *rowTag = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[self rowTagFromIndexPath:indexPath]];
        NSArray *rowData = [transactionTableDataDictionary objectForKey:rowTag];
        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString([rowData objectAtIndex:kCellHeightSelectorIndex]);
        rowHeight = [[self performSelector:selector withObject:tableView] floatValue];
    }

    return rowHeight;
}
```

Comment: This is happening to me as well, with one particular object. I would also like to know what's going on, as this might be causing other unforeseen bugs (leaks?).

Comment: I don't think this is leak related. I just added a code example where the issue happens to me on a object created on `init` and lives until `dealloc`. I'm really starting to think this my just be a bug in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Does `Car` inherit from `NSObject`?  Lots of functionality considered to be part of Objective-C depends on `NSObject`.

Comment: ...wich is actually part of the Cocoa framework, and not of the Objective-C language, I would like to add.

Comment: Nice idea, but yes Car does inherit NSObject